# Style element before adjacent selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, stylesheet

I've got a form with input texts (pseudo-code below):

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

And after submitting with errors in fields, script adds some `ul` lists with errors:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <ul class="errorlist">
      <li>This field has errors!</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I would like to add red border for the input with errors - I've tried this:

```
input + .errorlist{border: 1px solid red}
```

And it adds border to the ul elements, not input - I know why (I've read documentation) but I would like to invert this selector - something like this:

```
.errorlist + input{border: 1px solid red}
```

So summing up I would like to style element that is right **BEFORE** the other element (before answering please double-check my stylesheet and my HTML) - is there any way to achieve this with pure css?

Comment: No. Right now it is not possible.

Comment: The *script* should add a `class="error"` to the input element as well. So that you can use `input.error { /* ... */ }`

Comment: I know that I can add some class (this would be the simpliest way) but I didn't want to add any classes - I wanted to achieve this with pure css (but I'm not sure if it is possible).